# is there any way to make my carousel draggable?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I am having a problem about this carousel. I used bootstrap carousel template, just added my own images for the slide. I used jQuery for it to be draggable, ofcourse i added the cdn links. It is DRAGGABLE but it didn't change slides, why?

this is my code so far:

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/SCOVER_1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/SCOVER_2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/SCOVER_3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          // Make carousel items draggable
          $(".carousel-inner").draggable();
        });
        </script>
<style>
img {
    height: 625px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/ashamallah/pen/VwLqxpX refre this link may be it's helpful.

Comment: Do you mean draggable with the mouse? Bootstrap carousel already has touch-swipe. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#disable-touch-swiping

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Please see [ask], then revise to ask something more specific. Also, Draggable is a jQuery library. I don't see you loading jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Slick-Slider Plug-in for the slider/carousel.
It's RESPONSIVE, very user friendly and UI is very simple so you may easy to understand. Just you have to add the CDN of the slick-slider and you can also customize it as per your design.

Steps to use Slick-Slider:

1. Add CSS: [Slick CSS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css)
2. Add JS: [Slick JS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js)
3. Add the script in your file and add the class on which you want the slider. (This is sample script may differ as per design and requirement )

```js
$('.slider-class').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

Note: You can customize many things like how many slides will be shown or scroll at a time in the viewport, can make it in a loop, autoplay, etc...

For more details please refer to below links:
[Slick-Slider Official Site](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

[Slick-Slider Codepen](https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE)

Reference to get CDN Links:
[CDN Links reference](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/slick-carousel)