# CSS: width works bot height does not

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

trying to set the width of a div work without problems, but doing the exact same thing for the height won't work

I wanted to play around with the bootstrap carousel in codeply but it did not work as expected:

## HTML code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..." style="background-color: red;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..." style="background-color: yellow;">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..." style="background-color: blue;">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS code:

```
.carousel-item{
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px; }
```

Changes width but not height

Comment: Dİd you try  ```!important``` attribute for height ?

Comment: just add image element into class `.carousel-item img{`. your styles are added into carousel item and it has reflected in styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add image element into class .carousel-item img{. your styles are added into carousel item and it has reflected in styles.

edit

> Removed `w-100`class from image as it overrides the width custom css.

```css
.carousel-item img{
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="..." class="d-block" alt="..." style="background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="..." class="d-block" alt="..." style="background-color: yellow;">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="..." class="d-block" alt="..." style="background-color: blue;">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works to change the height, but does not change the width anymore. And I don't know why

Comment: You have added class `w-100` in image that overrides with !important in class.

Comment: OMG. Thank you! This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the height you need to try modify only height and leave the width as auto or unset

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 700px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you shared your code you've added the `w-100` class so w-100 class will make width = 100% !important as it is a class of Bootstrap.
And in the CSS file you're giving fixed width of 300px but as you marked w-100 in class 300px width will be ignored and will consider 100% of image's width and height will be 500px as you've given in the CSS file...

So your image will have dimensions like:
width = 100%;
height = 500px;

Note: as you've added d-block class width already will be 100% of your image's width so w-100 will work the same as the d-block.

Refer to this answer if you want to use slick-slider instead of Bootstrap.
[carousel/slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986028/is-there-any-way-to-make-my-carousel-draggable/75992464#75992464)